# Paragraph that is displayed in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/7w5Xv/621/

Code HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>text to appear when the user puts the mouse over</p>
</div>
```

Code CSS:

```
    div
{
    background:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

p
{
    display:none;
}
```

Code JQuery:

```
  $( 'div' ).hover( function () {

    $( 'p' )//What function should I use here? );

});
```

I want the paragraph to appear only when the user put the arrow over my div's.

How can i solve this problem?
Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7w5Xv/622/ doing some research before coming here helps sometimes. There is a ton of documentation and tutorials online. Googling also helps put you in the right direction. Searching for "mouse over div jquery event" and "show p jquery"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There so many ways to achieve this. See the method below.

```js
$(function() {
  var content; // Declare a variable
  content = $('p').text(); // assign the variable to the p's content only

  $('p').text(''); // Leave the content empty by default 

  $('p').mouseenter(function() {

    $(this).text(content); // Now show it on mouse enter

  }).mouseleave(function() { // empty on mouse leave
    $(this).text('');
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>text to appear when the user puts the mouse over</p>
```

**Note:** You can apply same method to the `DIV` and not the `P`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').hover(function () {
  $( 'p' ).show()
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: appreciate the comment msrd0.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as the others, only with the $(document).ready added in.

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $( 'div' ).hover( function () {

     $( 'p' ).show();

    });
  });

</script>
```

Depending on where your jquery code is located on the page -- $(document) may need to be declared. If its in the head section, its required.